# Set LatLangBound in GoogleMap

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am trying to set `LatLangBound` in map.When I give `SouthWest LatLang` & `NorthEast Latlang` of India, I am getting an error message that latitude of SouthWest > latitude of NorthEast (28.5827577 > 20.593684).
Is there any other way to display India regions when I start `MapFragment`.

My code snippet is.

```
private LatLngBounds India=new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(28.5827577,77.0334179),new LatLng(20.593684,78.96288));
mapView = (MapView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
mMap = mapView.getMap();
try {
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude, latitude), 6));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(India.getCenter(),6));
    CameraPosition cameraPosition =new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(latitude,latitude)).zoom(2).bearing(0).tilt(90).build();
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
}catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return rootview;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem at the end .

`mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new  LatLng(latitude,longitude),7.0f));`

It will move the camera focus at the given LatLng() and will zoom the map.

Answer (score 0):

use the com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds.Builder

Adapted to your source code it should look something like this:

```
Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
builder .include(currentLocationLatLng);
builder .include(targetLocationLatLng);
// pan to see all markers on map:
LatLngBounds bounds = builder .build();
googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 3));
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort vishal.